# Filtering list items depending on 8 columns

Tags: list

For a project i have made a custom list which calculates deadlines (document needs to be submitted before this date) depending on a start date (8 deadlines, 8 columns). Each row is another case with (possibly) another start date and other deadlines.

In another view it's possible to fill in when/if the document was submitted for each deadline (also 8 columns with date fields)

I would also need a view which shows all the rows where a deadline is overdue and there was no file submitted (no filled in date in the second view).

I have tried using a filter but it didn't work out, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to to filter out values based on date, you should use `[Today]` as a filter value in creating your view.

[image]

For example, if you want to show items whose dates **have not** passed the deadline, use the above. 'Less than' will filter out all dates beyond today's date. Just reverse the logic if you would like to show item whose dates **have** passed the deadline.

Hope this helps

Comment: yes this works for 1 deadline but not for all the deadlines (also there's a max of 10 filters and i need 16 (2 per column) )

Comment: Well then you're best off splitting into multiple views. Given SharePoint's limit to the number of filters

Comment: that's what I thought but it doesn't really look nice that way does it.. also will this work on more than column? I tried it and it didn't work..

Comment: What exactly did you try? This should work. Pattern should follow; "Column Name" > is less than/is greater than > [Today]

Comment: http://prntscr.com/aa6cbd

It should go on until evo 8 deadline, somehow when using the OR it doesnt split it as 2 different filters if u understand what i mean

Comment: Use a Calculated Column to merge all the logic of your 8 DueDates into one Column you can use in a Filter. eg. if D2 is empty then the calculated DueDate = D1, if D3 is empty then use D2 etc. etc.

Comment: Also, it seems conflicting that you would want to filter so many columns at once within a single view, as you will end up with a very reduced number of items being shown. I would have a filter (or two) per view.

Comment: yes indeed, thanks for the help anyway :)

@DannyEngelman, not a bad idea! i will try it this way, if I understand correctly i need to make a calculated column that decides which deadline is of matter, an then filter on that column?

Comment: Yes, and built your formulas in Notepad (and keep previous copies in the same file so you can learn from mistakes)... then paste from Notepad to SharePoint. Calculated Formulas are PITA to debug NOTE! You can **NOT** use Today in **CC Formulas**! See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a32871%20today

Comment: would you have a general formula i would have to follow? My knowledge of sharepoint is quite small

Comment: @DannyEngelman this is the formula I use for the first 2 deadlines and it works!
=IF(ISBLANK([Evo. 1 ingediend op]);[Deadline evo. 1];[Deadline evo. 2])

how should I complete the formula with more conditions?

Comment: @DannyEngelman, i completed the formula and it works, thanks!!